# How do I make a (minimal) runnable jar file from a scala eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, scala, build, jar

I have made a runnable jar using this process: http://garyboone.com/2009/06/creating-single-file-runnable-jars-in-scala-and-eclipse/?wscr=1366x768
editing the ant build.xml to include scala-library.jar (5.9 MB)

Isn't i possible somehow to get eclipse to extract the needed parts of scala-library.jar?
So I can get a smaller, less bloated jar file?

BR Troels

Answer (score 3):

Try using [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). An short tutorial is available [here](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2009/04/programming-for-android-with-scala.html) for the Android platform, but I think you can use it for your "normal" Scala applications, too.